# android studio switching language reloads app infinitely

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I am a complete beginner in android studio with java . I have created a navigation drawer where the homepage has a spinner to choose the app language . When the language changes the app reloads and succesfully applies the language changes . The problem is that the way my view is created the app reloads infinetely the moment it loads without me changing the language . So I need a way to tell it to reload my app only when I click on a different language .

My code :

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();
        Spinner spinner = root.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ImageView flags = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                CountryData.countryNames));
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                flags.setImageResource(CountryData.countryFlag[spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()]);
                String selectedLang = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                if(selectedLang.equals("GR")){
                    setLocal(HomeFragment.this,"el"); //app always reloads 
                }else {
                    setLocal(HomeFragment.this,"en"); //app always reloads 

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }


    public void setLocal(HomeFragment activity , String langCode){
      Locale locale = new Locale(langCode);
      locale.setDefault(locale);
      Resources resources = activity.getResources();
      Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
      config.setLocale(locale);
      resources.updateConfiguration(config,resources.getDisplayMetrics());
      getActivity().recreate(); //app reloads 
    }


}
```

I would appreciate your help

Comment: i think spinner always select first item by default when activity recreated it select first then again call the function..

Answer (score 1):

You can get a callback when configuration change in an Activity like orientation, locale etc...

override the **onConfigurationChanged** method in your activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   // here you can update UI
   //Checks the current language
   if (newConfig.locale == Locale.ENGLISH) {
      
   } 
}
```

Must needed to declare in Manifest `android:configChanges="locale"`

Comment: Could you provide a complete example with my code ? I am new to android and I would appreciate your help

Comment: Try this: https://akexorcist.dev/localization-activity-best-way-to-support-several-language/